# Redirect on WWW only to non www domain NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, www

I'm confused, does this additional server block will redirect ANY subdomain to `https://example.com`?

```
     server { 
         server_name www.example.com
         return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
     }
```

As far as I read it is bad practice to do it like this

```
        if ($host ~* ^www\.) {
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
```

But, at least in this case I'm sure that it is only rewrite if WWW is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server_name` directive matches on the `Host` request header. By specifying "www.example.com", that server block only applies to requests who's Host header matches that exact domain name.

See nginx [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) for more details.